# List all dependencies for package

Tags: ubuntu, apt, jails

I am configuring a ubuntu 14.04 server, for making it more secure 
 i wanted to jail each user to his home directory. So far this worked as expected.

But-;)-i am installed  a complete RoR environment via `rbenv` while being 
`root`. So my gem files resist under `/root/.gem/` and after sshd restart
i was not able anymore to use  `bunder` or `rails` anymore. 
My quick and dirty idea was now to change the group of the `.gem` folder for my username so that he again has access. I have not tried it yet but would that be the right way?
And how to find all the dependencies for my RoR environment. There might be more folder whose group i have to change.
Since i did not use `apt` i need a manual way i guess but i do not know how to do this.

Comment: Have you seen [RVM](https://rvm.io/)?

Comment: yes i have, but i dont see the advantage?